# Password encoding symfony 3

Tags: php, symfony

I try to make a simple module in order to register.
Anytime when I submit the form, this error occur:

> Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoder::encodePassword() must implement interface Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface, string given, called in ...

I read this article but is not clear how to implement `UserPasswordEncoderInterface`.

This is my action method:

```
public function registerAction(UserPasswordEncoderInterface $encoder, Request $request){
       $user = new User();
        $form = $this->createFormBuilder($user)
                     ->add('username', TextType::class, array('label' => 'Username', 'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control')))
                     ->add('password', PasswordType::class, array('label' => 'Password', 'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control')))
                     ->add('register', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Register', 'attr' => array('class' => 'btn btn-default')))
                     ->getForm();

        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){
         $user->setRoles(array('ROLE_ADMIN')); ///ROLE_USER
         $encoded = $encoder->encodePassword($user->getUsername(), $user-getPassword());
         $user->setPassword($encoded);
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($user);
            $em->flush();
            return $this->redirectToRoute('login');
        }

       return $this->render('register.html.twig', ['form' => $form-createView()] );
     }
```

Comment: Think about what the error message is telling you.  The first argument needs to be a $user object, you are passing the user name.  Sometimes it helps to look at the actual component source code.  You should be able to view the UserPasswordEncoder source code using a control key from inside your IDE.

Comment: try to change this line `$encoder->encodePassword($user->getUsername(), $user-getPassword());` to this `$encoder->encodePassword($user, $user-getPassword());`

Answer (score 1):

Indeed

$encoded = $encoder->encodePassword($user, $user->getPassword());

thanks Cerad!